# straUnexpected output xsl:value-of

Tags: xslt-2.0

Havin a strange issue again. I am tryinodo a simple value- of of field CRETIM:

```
        <CREDAT>20220628</CREDAT>
        <CRETIM>112159</CRETIM>



        <xsl:attribute name="timestamp">
            

        
                <xsl:value-of select="EDI_DC40/CRETIM" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
a
        </xsl:attribute>
```

Output looks as follows:

[image: enter image deOutputscription here]
First6 characterrs are ok, but no idea what happened to th rest.Any idea whats wrong here and how this can be fixed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If that is XSLT 2 I wonder why you don't use the `select` attribute on `xsl:attribute` e.g. `<xsl:attribute name="timestamp" select="EDI_DC40/CRETIM"/>`.

If you use `xsl:value-of` wrapped into `xsl:attribute` make sure you have stray data (like that `a` letter) inside of `xsl:attribute`. If the sole `a` letter is intentional then use e.g. `<xsl:attribute name="timestamp" select="concat(EDI_DC40/CRETIM, 'a')"/>` or `<xsl:attribute name="timestamp"><xsl:value-of select="EDI_DC40/CRETIM"/>a</xsl:attribute>`.